# Writing query for manual index rebuild for tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I have some multiple tables to rebuild index on sql server.
For example there are 20 tables to be index rebuild .
I would like to rebuild table manually by command 
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[carwash] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
How can i loop my command so that i can rebuild my 20 tables one by one instead of doing copy paste 20times.One more condition i would like to do one by one not all at once, for example like when first table rebuild is success then go to second table and like wise third ..fourth .

Iam just doing this manually at the moment can you guide me how to put this query in a loop so that i don't have to do it manually
ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[carwash] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);

Answer (score 0):

you can generate all commands with Cursor+DQE.

i generate all rebuild command with this code furthermore  you can execute automatically with EXEC() command

this code generate Rebuild command for all tables of db you can filter your tables with core query of Cursor

```
DECLARE @SchemaName nvarchar(50) , @TableName nvarchar(50) , @Command varchar(max)


DECLARE Rebuild_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'


OPEN Rebuild_Cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM Rebuild_Cursor 
INTO @SchemaName,@TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    PRINT('ALTER INDEX ALL ON ['+@SchemaName +'].'+@TableName + ' REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON) ')

FETCH NEXT FROM Rebuild_Cursor 
INTO @SchemaName,@TableName
END
CLOSE Rebuild_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Rebuild_Cursor
```

and you can use this query for generate your command but if you want execute these command automatically you can write one loop  or cursor and execute command per row

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].' + TABLE_NAME+ ' REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON) '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. How do i put for example i have tables dbo.a , abo.b, dbo.C,dbo.D,dbo.E like that and currently iam using ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[a] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON); and if it is successfull then ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[B] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON); if success ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[C] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON); ..like wise it goes on .

Comment: you can create a job with many state dynamically and set next step behavior of your job fail if one step dont work. is it OK for your problem?? @sandeep